# Spreadsheets: Update a column in one sheet if it matches to a column in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Suppose I have two google sheets. Say, sheet1 and sheet2

Suppose sheet1 looks like this

[image]

Now, sheet2 contains same elements as sheet1 in column A, but not in same order.

[image]

I need to fill the column B in sheet2, the corresponding entries from sheet1,programatically, so that sheet2 looks like this

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

Sheet 2 B1:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet1!A:B,2,0))
```

So, We're looking up a array of A:A in Sheet 1A:B and asking [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)  to return the 2nd column in the sheet 1 array.

Comment: I want description for `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet1!A:B,2,0))`

Comment: Done.⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆⬆

Comment: tried this. got `Error
VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.`

Comment: That's just sad.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-sheets/gdmgbiccnalapanbededmeiadjfbfhkl) which does exactly that: **merges** sheets to get another one with combined data.